# Problems With Pushing Java Array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, for-loop

Im trying to make an array which includes all letters(characters) in the char variable. But when I try to push more letters onto it (`CharArray[].push(counter);`), it gives me an error. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
    char[] CharArray = {};
    char counter = 'a';

    for(int i = 1; i <= 26; i++) {
        CharArray[].push(counter);
        counter++;
    }
```

Comment: This looks like...a strange hybrid of JavaScript and Java.  The two languages are *not* the same as one another.

Comment: There is no push method in a plain Java array. You may use an ArrayList or ArrayDeque instead.

Comment: I thought pushing on an array would work... maybe not

Comment: So how would I add characters?

Comment: Check this java docs for arrays it should give you an idea https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: `char[] CharArray = new char[26];  CharArray[i] = counter;`

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want.

```
char[] CharArray = new char[26];
char counter = 'a';

for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    CharArray[i]=counter;
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is works well. That is what I was sort of going for

Answer (score 0):

- There is better solution for pushing symbols in array. It is an ArrayList.

  ```
  ArrayList<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();
  for (char symbol = 'a'; symbol <= 'z'; symbol++) {
    characters.add(symbol);
  }
  ```
- You should use camel Case notation in naming of variables.